# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time' site:stackoverflow.com

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to subtract values of two datetime objects like the following:

```
df["Time Taken"] = (pd.to_datetime(df['end_time']).dt.tz_convert('Asia/Kolkata').dt.time) - \
                           (pd.to_datetime(df['start_time']).dt.tz_convert('Asia/Kolkata').dt.time)
```

in a Dataframe like the following:

```
     id                    serial reference_number                         date                warehouse          owner                   start_time                     end_time
0  352                 655556555             5002  2022-05-15T13:33:00.208423Z  Delhivery Goa Warehouse  Delhivery_Goa  2022-05-31T11:26:10.977240Z  2022-05-31T11:59:55.421159Z
1  362  E2806995000040043136895A             5007  2022-05-18T10:37:28.871625Z  Delhivery Goa Warehouse  Delhivery_Goa  2022-05-31T11:26:10.977240Z  2022-05-31T11:59:55.421159Z
2  363  E28069950000500431368519             5008  2022-05-18T10:44:32.398842Z  Delhivery Goa Warehouse  Delhivery_Goa  2022-05-31T11:26:10.977240Z  2022-05-31T11:59:55.421159Z
3  364  E28069950000400431368536             5008  2022-05-18T10:44:32.398842Z  Delhivery Goa Warehouse  Delhivery_Goa  2022-05-31T11:26:10.977240Z  2022-05-31T11:59:55.421159Z
4  370  E28069950000500431368549             5010  2022-05-18T12:30:34.599759Z  Delhivery Goa Warehouse  Delhivery_Goa  2022-05-31T11:26:10.977240Z  2022-05-31T11:59:55.421159Z
```

I tried `timedelta` as well but the I got the following error:

> only leading negative signs are allowed

How do I do it?

Comment: What's the `.dt.time` for? Just subtracting datetime columns should work and give you timedeltas. Times themselves (`datetime.time`) don't support subtraction because without a date you won't know if the two times are 33 minutes or 24 hours and 33 minutes apart, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First subtract columns converted to datetimes by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html), for seconds use [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html)::

```
df["Time Taken"] = (pd.to_datetime(df['end_time']).sub(pd.to_datetime(df['start_time']))
                      .dt.total_seconds())
```

For format `HH:MM:SS` from timedeltas use:

```
def f(x):
    ts = x.total_seconds()
    hours, remainder = divmod(ts, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    return ('{}:{:02d}:{:02d}').format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds)) 

df["Time Taken"] = (pd.to_datetime(df['end_time']).sub(pd.to_datetime(df['start_time']))
                      .apply(f))
```

Answer (score -1):

You're making this way more complicated than it needs to be:

Just

```
df["Time Taken"] = (
    pd.to_datetime(df['end_time'])
    - pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'])
)
```

This should give you a column of timedeltas which you can format as you wish.

Steps you can skip:

- Converting the time zone. The times in the database already specify specific points in time, so the difference can be calculated. Converting from UTC to local doesn't change the result.
- Extracting the time from the date with `.dt.time`. This is what causes the error because times don't support subtraction. Subtraction isn't implemented for these because the concept of a difference between two times isn't well-defined. Like is (1am - 4am) -3 hours or +21 hours or even -2 or -4 hours because a switch between daylight savings and normal time occured?