# Calculate time difference based on unique entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
Trip_nr Time1 Time2
1       08:00 05:17
1       08:05 05:18
1       08:40 05:19
2       10:42 08:10
2       10:50 08:11
3       21:00 16:23
3       21:04 16:24
3       21:07 16:25
3       21:09 16:26
```

For each Trip_nr I want to generate the following output:

1. find earliest Time1
2. find latest Time1
3. find earliest Time2
4. find latest Time2

I then want to show the output in the following format (also data frame)

```
unique_trip_nr earliest_Time1 latest_Time1 earliest_Time2 latest_Time2
1              08:00          08:40        05:17          05:19
2              10:42          10:50        08:10          08:11
3              21:00          21:09        16:23          16:26
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`named aggregation`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation):

```
df = df.groupby('Trip_nr', as_index=False).agg(earliest_Time1=('Time1','min'),
                                               latest_Time1=('Time1','max'),
                                               earliest_Time2=('Time2','min'),
                                               latest_Time2=('Time2','max'))
print (df)
   Trip_nr earliest_Time1 latest_Time1 earliest_Time2 latest_Time2
0        1          08:00        08:40          05:17        05:19
1        2          10:42        10:50          08:10        08:11
2        3          21:00        21:09          16:23        16:26
```

Comment: As a follow up: would there be a way to subtract i.e. (latest_Time1 - earliest_Time1)? As both values are strings, this seems complicated..

Comment: @Lwins - Use `df['diff1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['latest_Time1'], format='%H:%M').sub(pd.to_datetime(df['earliest_Time1'], format='%H:%M'))`

Comment: @Lwins - for convert timedeltas to strings use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72447369/2901002)  - `df['diff1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['latest_Time1'], format='%H:%M').sub(pd.to_datetime(df['earliest_Time1'], format='%H:%M')).apply(f)`

Comment: thanks - what is the f in "apply(f)"?

Comment: function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/72447369/2901002